# Transportadora braspress e WordPress woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

estou desenvolvendo um woocommerce para um cliente eo mês.o utiliza correios e transportadora braspress, mas não achei uma solução para braspress, alguém poderia me ajudar, existe um plugin do Cláudio Sanches mas parece q não foi finalizado, existe talvez alguma forma no woocommerce de coloca frete por faixa de preços acho.q.resolveria, alguém poderia me ajudar ? Obrigado.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT: recomendo que faça o [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e adicione um [mvce](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: O titulo não tem nada haver com o que é que perguntado, transportadora braspress é uma empresa (até aonde sei) e nada tem haver com a tecnologia citada e o que precisa. A questão é: É um site? "Sim"; A empresa A ou B interfere na solução da tecnologia? "Acho que não", então não entendo o que você quer dizer com "uma solução para braspress", a não ser que esteja falando de algum webservice... É isso?

Answer (score 1):

O titulo não tem nada haver com o que é que perguntado, transportadora braspress é uma empresa (até aonde sei) e nada tem haver com a tecnologia citada e o que precisa. A questão é: É um site? "Sim"; A empresa A ou B interfere na solução da tecnologia? "Acho que não", então não entendo o que você quer dizer com "uma solução para braspress", a não ser que esteja falando de algum webservice... É isso?

Não encontrei nada pronto pra Wordpress, mas o wordpress é escrito em PHP então existe este repositório no Github pode ajudar https://github.com/ivanwhm/braspress

Classe:

- https://github.com/ivanwhm/braspress/tree/master/classes

Exemplos:

- https://github.com/ivanwhm/braspress/tree/master/exemplos

Como calcular frete:

```
//Ajusta a codificação e o tipo do conteúdo
header('Content-type: text/txt; charset=utf-8');

//Importa as classes
require '../classes/Braspress.php';
require '../classes/BraspressCalculaFrete.php';
require '../classes/BraspressCalculaFreteResultado.php';

try
{
  //Cria o objeto
  $consulta = new BraspressCalculaFrete(00000000000000);
  $consulta->setIdOrigem(2);
  $consulta->setCepOrigem(89010130);
  $consulta->setCepDestino(88095001);
  $consulta->setDocumentoDestino(00000000000);
  $consulta->setTipoFrete(Braspress::TIPO_FRETE_RODOVIARIO);
  $consulta->setPeso(1500);
  $consulta->setValorNF(123);
  $consulta->setVolume(1);
  if ($consulta->processaConsulta())
  {
    $retorno = $consulta->getResultado();
    //Se teve erro
    if ($retorno->getSucesso())
    {
      //Imprime o resultado
      echo 'Valor total do frete............: ' . number_format($retorno->getTotalFrete(), 2, ',', '.') . PHP_EOL;
      echo 'Percentual de ICMS..............: ' . number_format($retorno->getIcms(), 0, ',', '.') . '%' . PHP_EOL;
      echo 'Valor do ICMS...................: ' . number_format($retorno->getValorIcms(), 2, ',', '.') . PHP_EOL;
      echo 'Valor do frete peso.............: ' . number_format($retorno->getFretePeso(), 2, ',', '.') . PHP_EOL;
      echo 'Valor do frete valor............: ' . number_format($retorno->getFreteValor(), 2, ',', '.') . PHP_EOL;
      echo 'Valor da taxa de seção cadastro.: ' . number_format($retorno->getTaxaSecaoCad(), 2, ',', '.') . PHP_EOL;
      echo 'Valor da taxa de pedágio........: ' . number_format($retorno->getTaxaPedagio(), 2, ',', '.') . PHP_EOL;
      echo 'Valor da taxa de despacho.......: ' . number_format($retorno->getTaxaDespacho(), 2, ',', '.') . PHP_EOL;
      echo 'Valor da taxa de ITR............: ' . number_format($retorno->getTaxaITR(), 2, ',', '.') . PHP_EOL;
      echo 'Valor da taxa de ademe..........: ' . number_format($retorno->getTaxaAdeme(), 2, ',', '.') . PHP_EOL;
      echo 'Valor das outras taxas..........: ' . number_format($retorno->getTaxaOutros(), 2, ',', '.') . PHP_EOL;
      echo 'Valor do subtotal do frete......: ' . number_format($retorno->getSubtotal(), 2, ',', '.') . PHP_EOL;
      echo 'Prazo de entrega................: ' . $retorno->getPrazoEntrega() . PHP_EOL;
    } else
      echo 'Ocorreu um erro. Mensagem: ' . $retorno->getMensagemErro() . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
  } else
    echo 'Ocorreu um erro, tente novamente mais tarde.' . PHP_EOL;
} catch (Exception $e)
{
  echo 'Ocorreu um erro ao processar sua solicitação. Erro: ' . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
```